# How to call C# method from AS3 script?

Tags: flash, unity-game-engine

I have two swf files. First (let's call it A) one is a kind of host application with login UI, etc. The second one (B) is generated by Unity. So, A after some actions from user load and starts B. At this point I can easily call B (AS3) method from A (C#) and it works, but I can't call A (C#) methods from B (AS3). There is no any information about this direction communication on [official documentation page](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/flash-gettingstarted.html).

So, I've tried [this way](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/147415-Call-AS3-function-from-C-and-Call-C-function-from-AS3-maybe-helpful), but it doesn't work for me. So what I've done:

on C# (project A) side I've created FlashCB.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[NotRenamed]
public class FlashCB {

    public static int Func() {
        Debug.Log("Unity function called with message. ");
        return 10;
    }
}
```

on AS3 (project B) side NetTest.as:

```
import global.FlashCB;
[...]
public function onLoadComplete( evt : Event ) : void
{
    [...]
    var res:int = FlashCB.Func();
}
```

Finally, it crashes with this error:

```
[Fault] exception, information=ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable FlashCB is not defined.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's about Unity, but I've also made a C# app with Flash inside.
I used this code, and it works fine:

AS3:

```
ExternalInterface.call('myfunction', >params<);
```

C#:

```
flashPlayer.FlashCall += new _IShockwaveFlashEvents_FlashCallEventHandler(flashPlayer_FlashCall); //this var is your Flash
private void flashPlayer_FlashCall(object sender, _IShockwaveFlashEvents_FlashCallEvent e)
{
    //your flash call handler here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I'm looking for. I have a C# Unity project which is converted to AS3 (swf) and have to communicate with another nested swf.